# What is the opposite of the indent block Ctrl-V + I .... <ESC>? To unindent a block of few characters by removing few contiguous columns on lines?

Tags: vim

I'm found of <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> *select your block* <kbd>I</kbd> *type yours characters* <kbd>ESC</kbd>
with *vim*, that helps a lot to indent a block by adding few characters on its left.

Very useful to put `>` when you forgotten them, for example!

But how to do the opposite?
Unindent a block, but the same way I've indented it: by removing few contiguous columns of selected lines?

```
# I have this text:
   ABC%/1234
   DEF$-542
   GHI§*756
   JKL£^288
```

I want to shift left my text for two columns for some of its lines.
Remove the:

```
%/
$-
§*
```

characters that are disturbing me on columns 7 and 8 on three of the four lines of data.

Starting with the caret on the `%` of my text,
what block command and other command should I type to achieve the result I'm willing? This one:

```
# I have this text:
   ABC1234
   DEF542
   GHI756
   JKL£^288
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual-block mode is just a special case of visual mode: once you have selected the text you want to delete, well… press `d` to delete it.

The various visual modes are introduced in chapter 4 of the user manual, `:help usr_04`, with the example for visual-block mode being pretty much exactly what you want to do:

```
<C-v><motion>d
```

I would suggest you take the time to learn Vim properly instead of trying random commands found on the web:

```
:help user-manual
```

Comment: Thanks for your response that is correct. But I have no time for stopping and learning _vim_ aside. Like many people, I've plenty of work to do elsewhere.

Comment: Make time for learning it or stop using it. If you have to ask strangers for help for every basic thing then you will never rip any benefit. There are more approachable tools for the impatient out there.

Comment: You are wrong: I'm using it every day with benefits, but few actions I'm stumbling upon.